# Reference to complete derivation of Kossakowski–Lindblad equation and its steady solutions

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-mechanics

Are there recommended textbook or good intro-reference to explain with complete stretch of [Kossakowski–Lindblad equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindblad_equation) especially how is the idea to derive it from ground?

$$\dot\rho=-{i\over\hbar}[H,\rho]+\sum_{n,m = 1}^{N^2-1} h_{n,m}\big(L_n\rho L_m^\dagger-\frac{1}{2}\left(\rho L_m^\dagger L_n + L_m^\dagger L_n\rho\right)\big).$$

And how does it look like for the steady solutions.

Comment: Cross-posted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/687149/11127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following two articles http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2122 (A simple derivation of the Lindblad equation, by Carlos Alexandre Brasil, Felipe Fernandes Fanchini, Reginaldo de Jesus Napolitano) and http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.2016 (Simple Derivation of the Lindblad Equation, by Philip Pearle. The published version is http://iopscience.iop.org/0143-0807/33/4/805/) are quite good as an introduction to the subject.

Answer (score 0):

In the first paper (A simple derivation of the Lindblad equation, by Carlos Alexandre Brasil, Felipe Fernandes Fanchini, Reginaldo de Jesus Napolitano) there is an assumption that is not always true (equation 16) and without this assumption this result is not drivable. For example consider an open quantum system composed of a 3-level \Lambda-type atomic system interacting with two classical fields (control field and probe field). Can anyone help with that?

Comment: Did you mean to ask a follow-up question? MO works differently to a discussion forum, you'd need to hit the Ask Question button, post this there, and link back to this question for additional context (while aiming to be reasonably self-contained). This post counts in the software (and by users) as an answer...but it's not really, though it's definitely related. You might get a downvote for not following the usual practice (i hope not), but please don't let that deter you. Hope that helps!